# Is there a magic method to know that a base class is used through inheritance?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to describe my problem with code to make it clear:

```
class MyBaseClass(object):

   def __init__(self):
       print 'foobar'

   def __call__(self):
      print 'spameggs'


   def __is_used__(self): # This is only a pseudo method
       print 'I\'m being used! - MyBaseClass'


class MySubClass(MyBaseClass):

    def __init__(self):
        print 'monty python'
```

Now I'd like to know if there is a similar magic method *`__is_used__`* for a class object to know if it is being use as a parent/base class of another class (sub)?

Example usage:

```
class_a = MySubClass()

# Output
# monty python
# I'm being used! - MyBaseClass
```

**Use Case**

To avoid confusion *(I apologize)*. A best example would be a mixin. Example an `S3Mixin`.

An `S3Mixin` has a capabilities to upload and download file to S3 buckets.

```
class S3Mixin(object):

    def upload(self):

    def download(self):
```

Now i want to use it to `ImageFile` and `VideoFile` classes.

```
class ImageFile(S3Mixin):

    # omitted lengthy properties

class VideoFile(S3Mixin):

    # omitted lengthy properties
```

Now each object has a function to use the s3 basic functionalities. Now the real problem arise when I try to use another module inside a S3Mixin which cause a circular dependency issue. Now to avoid it I have to import it inside each function of S3Mixin. I tried putting it on the `__init__` method and `__call__` method which is obviously not going to work.

I don't want to do that. Instead I wanted to know if there is available method so I can import all the conflicted module preferable on a magic method of an S3Mixin.

**Note:**

I'm not asking for a checking of a class that is a subclass of another class. That is far from the question. I would like to know if there is a **MAGIC METHOD** so i can further create a logic in it when a base class is used.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188907/discussion-on-question-by-roel-is-there-a-magic-method-to-know-that-a-base-class).